# Alternative to NetworkStream.Read that indicates remote host has closed the connection?

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, tcpclient, networkstream

With regards to handling a TCP/IP connection using the `TcpClient` class, is there an alternative for checking whether the remote host has closed the connection other than waiting for the `NetworkStream.Read` method to return a 0?

Comment: You don't want to wait?  BeginRead().  EndRead() throws an exception.

Comment: @nobugz: In addition to catching an exception, are there other alternatives?

Comment: Remember you will only receive notifications of a remote host closing a connection *if* the remote host gracefully closes the connection.  The result is you usually will want to have a timeout which closes a connection after a certain period of inactivity.   Dependent on your protocol, you may also wish to occasionally send messages to the host since a write operation will allow you to quickly determine if the host still has the connection open or has non-gracefully closed the connection.

Comment: @HansPassant No, it does not throw an exception when using `BeginRead()` and `EndRead()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues` on the `TcpClient.Client` to guarantee that a keep-alive check is made at least on the specified interval and then check the `TcpClient.Client.Connected` property.

An example how to use it:

```
struct tcp_keepalive
{
    public int OnOff;
    public int KeepAliveTime;
    public int KeepAliveInterval;

    public unsafe byte[] Buffer
    {
        get
        {
            var buf = new byte[sizeof(tcp_keepalive)];
            fixed(void* p = &this) Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(p), buf, 0, buf.Length);
            return buf;
        }
    }
};

static void KeepAliveTest()
{
    using(var c = new TcpClient())
    {
        c.Connect("www.google.com", 80);
        var s = c.Client;
        var ka = new tcp_keepalive();
        ka.OnOff = 1; // enable
        ka.KeepAliveTime = 1000 * 60; // 60 seconds of inactivity allowed
        ka.KeepAliveInterval = 1000; // 1 second interval on keep-alive checks (default)
        s.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, ka.Buffer, null);
        var ns = c.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
        while(true)
        {
            SocketError se;
            s.Blocking = false;
            s.Receive(new byte[0], 0, 0, SocketFlags.Peek, out se);
            s.Blocking = true;
            if(!s.Connected)
            {
                // se==SocketError.ConnectionReset||SocketError.NetworkReset if the connection was closed because of a keep-alive check
                Console.WriteLine("Socket disconnected: " + se);
                break;
            }
            // do other stuff
            if(ns.DataAvailable) ns.Read(new byte[100], 0, 100);
            else Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues are set using bytes as the second parameter for the Socket.IOControl Method. What is the no of bytes to use and is the value to be set in seconds or milliseconds? Can't seem to find the answers to the above mentioned questions from the following MSDN site. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a3744sh.aspx

Comment: SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS documentation is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220(VS.85).aspx